# implementing next and previous buttons(LinkedList)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some LinkedList. I filled it with some DataTable from DataSet. So question is how do I implement button "Next" and "Previous" on Windows Form to navigate my tables?

```
LinkedListNode<DataTable> lln = new 
LinkedListNode<DataTable(ds.Tables("GRAPHICS"))
LinkedList<DataTable> ll = new LinkedList<DataTable>
LinkedListClass.ll.AddFirst(lln)
LinkedListClass.ll.AddLast(ds.Tables("COORDS"))
LinkedListClass.ll.AddLast(ds.Tables("METHODS"))
```

I expect to press button "Next" get table "`COORDS`" and press "`Previous`" button get previous value ( "`GRAPHICS`" table)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to store a current position. So add i.e. a property that stores the current item's table name. Than add two "click" events for your buttons(previous and next) and handle these events. Something like this

```
private string _currentTableName; // or reference list item directly

// use this pseudo code to create "Previous" method as well 
void NextButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get current element using stored name
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentTableName))
    {
        _currentTableName = firstElement.Name;
        // show first
        Display(firstElement);
    }
    else 
    {
         // get current element 
         // get next element
         _currentTableName = nextElement.Name;
         Display(nextElement);
    }
}
```